# What is the ASTERIX terminology for an atomic piece of information?

Tags: terminology, icao, asterix

The [ASTERIX](https://www.eurocontrol.int/services/asterix) standard defines the smallest piece of metadata information:

> Data Item: The smallest unit of information in each Data Category.

And the implementation equivalent:

> Data Field: Physical implementation for the purpose of communication
>   of a Data Item, it is associated with a unique Field Reference Number
>   and is the smallest unit of transmitted information.

But, neither of them are atomic. The most common example is Data Source Identifier (SIC/SAC) which contains two pieces of information: SIC and SAC. For instance, such a Data Item is defined in the [048 Category](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/publication/files/Cat048pt4ed123.pdf):

> Data Item I048/010, Data Source Identifier Identification of the radar
>   station from which the data are received. Two-octet fixed length Data
>   Item.
>   bits-16/9 (SAC) System Area Code
>   bits-8/1 (SIC) System Identification Code

So my question is: what is an atomic (minimal) piece of information called in the ASTERIX standard?

Comment: There is no official name for that unfortunately. I call it `element`.

Comment: The spec does not appear to define what is an atomic piece of information, likely because it assumes the implementer already knows the answer. From what I see, the equivalent of what you seek from the point of view of the spec is the data item.

Comment: Can someone please edit this to make the relationship to aviation apparent?

Comment: @MichaelHall I added usage guidance and wiki entry to the [asterix] tag. That should make the relationship to aviation clear. Note that our [on-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help center page includes *air traffic control*.

Comment: @Bianfable, I don’t see “air traffic control” anywhere in the question.  If that is the connection, a simple one line sentence in plain language would be nice.  Otherwise this seems as relevant as asking a question about aluminum atoms.  (Airplanes are made of aluminum, so…). This ties in with our other commentary about the relevance of atmospheric questions.  I realize we all come to this site with different aviation experience and interest, but I should have to perform research just to get a high level grasp of of the what the question is about.

Comment: There are many questions here that go way over my head, but I can at least recognize the relationship to aviation and know when to pass, or when I might offer some good insight.  I’m not asking for much here, something as simple as “the ASTERIX standard for developing air traffic control software code…” would establish the connection.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHall, There are no objections from my side to modifying the question or removing it at all. But first I think we need to clarify if surveillance radars and their communication protocol can be considered as part of the "Air Traffic Control" topic?

Comment: Is this question about surveillance radars and their communication protocol?  Because if it is, then simply state that and I will just shut up and sit down.  But “atomic piece of information”?!

Comment: @Gluttton please edit your question as requested, so that it is more accessible for readers without prior knowledge of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Although this term is not used, you can call each piece under data item is a data field.